# Parameter Query Where Contents Determine Both Property Name and Property Value Assigned

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two values extracted from a select query on a MySQL database. The first contains the property name and the second contains the value for the property.

Is there a way using a parameter to assign the value to the name in the first field i.e. Something like

SET name in row.Property_Name=row.Property_Value

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do so with Cypher only: the [`n[name]`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/cypher/syntax/expressions/#_expressions_in_general) syntax allows you to [read](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/cypher/clauses/where/#where-filter-on-dynamic-node-property) but not write a property with a dynamic name.

However, you can do it with an [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) procedure, even though it's currently missing from the documentation: `apoc.create.setProperty()`. It's in the [3.0](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/53b8a73/src/main/java/apoc/create/Create.java#L50) and [3.1](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3e4e8e6/src/main/java/apoc/create/Create.java#L44) branches of APOC, so you're good to go with any Neo4j 3.x instance.

```
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(n, row.Property_Name, row.Property_Value)
```

Comment: Looks promising. Not there yet. Getting error:

Procedure call inside a query does not support naming results implicitly (name explicitly using `YIELD` instead) (line 18, column 3 (offset: 720))
"  CALL apoc.create.setProperty(n, row.Property_Name, row.Property_Value)"

Answer (score 1):

If you can change these key/value pairs into a map, then you can set them on nodes.

The syntax, if map has been changed to a parameter, looks like this for a column of nodes n:

```
SET n += $map
```

You may want to review the [SET clause](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/set/) in the documentation.